# Sending email on behalf of other user for office365-outlook

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

I am sending an email using a console application created using C#.I want to send this email with a different `From name`, I have found the same code on many sites, but it is not working in my case.

`MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("xyz@abc.com", "Sender");`

I am using office365- outlook.

My complete code is:-

```
 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 25);
            MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("xyz@abc.com", "Mailer");
            MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress("xyz@abc.com");
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);

            mailt.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mailt.Body = "This is for testing";

            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@abc.com", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

So in this case is it possible to change the sender name for sending email or can we send email on behalf of other user in outlook using code?

Comment: Are you targeting any email client installed on the system, or Outlook specifically? Or a specific kind of email account (Exchange, IMAP, POP)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Outlook` [object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/outlook-object-model-overview?view=vs-2019), you can do:

```
Outlook.Application OL = ....;
Outlook._MailItem mail;

mail = OL.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook._MailItem;
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
mail.HTMLBody = body;

//  add recipients
//  ....

mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender;
mail.Send();
```

This requires `Outlook` to be installed on your system.

To get hints about what could be wrong with your code, you should describe the error messages or failure you are getting.

Comment: I am able to send email using my code but the sender name is not coming as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
    mail.From = new MailAddress("test@example.com");
```